# c# count strings in list with certain length

Tags: c#, .net, list, count

I'm having a List WordList filled with words:

```
List<string> WordList = new List<string> { 
  "BED", "CAT", "JUG", "BOAT", "FRUIT", "LABEL", "MOTOR", "SCORE" };
```

I want to count how many 3, 4 and 5 letter words there are in the list.
I can of course loop over all words and check their length, but there must be a better way.
Anyone has any ideas on this?

Comment: Look for `GroupBy` method from `System.Linq` namespace. There are tons of such questions and answers in SO.

Comment: This looks like a "lazyness" question. At least provide an example of what you've tried so far instead of just let the others do the work for you.

Comment: You can't do better than O(n). Looping manually or using ling is essentially the same and they're both O(n).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could group values on length of the string:

```
var result = WordList.GroupBy(s => s.Length)
                     .Select(x => new {x.Key, Amount = x.Count()});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great and is a lot easier to read than to loop over the whole list.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `GroupBy` will do

```
  List<string> WordList = new List<string> { 
    "BED", "CAT", "JUG", "BOAT", "FRUIT", "LABEL", "MOTOR", "SCORE" };

  var result = WordList
    .GroupBy(word => word.Length, 
             (key, data) => $"Letters: {key} Count: {data.Count()}");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
Letters: 3 Count: 3
Letters: 4 Count: 1
Letters: 5 Count: 4
```

Comment: nice, didn't knew about this overload, +1